# Can I make aol.com my default email reader in Mavericks instead of Mail?

Tags: mail.app

An AOL rep reset my Safari, and since then, whenever I hit <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> it brings up mail instead of italicizing words. How can I change back?

Comment: There seems to be two overlapping questions here. Can you narrow this down to one question per question and ask the other separately if necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have the AOL mail installed on your system,

go to Apple Mail  (open it)- preferences

Select the Default mail reader to AOL.

The <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>i</kbd> is standard Safari keyboard shortcut to open your default email (AOL) and to send the current webpage- nothing to do with AOL setting it up.